# Using QML OpacityMask to round off upper corners of overlayed rectangle

Tags: qt, qml, rectangles, opacitymask

I am trying to create a rounded rectangle, with the top portion filled with a solid color, and lower portion filled with text.  I am overlaying the upper portion of the rounded rectangle (**outerRectangle** in white with black border) with another rectangle (**innerTopRectangle** in red).  However, instead of rounding off the top of my innerTopRectangle, it's rounding off the BOTTOM corners:

[image]

I wanted **innerTopRectangle** to be rounded off at the top (clipped and within the **outerRectangle** border), but flat on the bottom.

Can someone suggest what's wrong?  Logically my opacitymask top should anchor to my innerTopRectangle I think, and since innerTopRectangle is not as tall only the top corners should be masked.

```
Rectangle {
    id: outerRectangle
    width: (parent.width / 2) - 5 - 10;
    height: 40
    anchors.margins: 10
    border {
        width: 2
        color: "#120e0d"
    }
    clip: true
    radius: 5
    Rectangle {
        id: innerTopRectangle
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: OpacityMask {
            anchors.top: outerRectangle.top
            maskSource: outerRectangle
        }
        height: parent.height - levelName.height
        color: "red"
    }  // Inner top rectable


    Text {
        id: levelName
        anchors {
            top: innerTopRectangle.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        text: name
    }  // Text
}  // Outer rectangle
```

Comment: The bottom corners are rounded because you gave a radius to outerRectangle. Your OpacityMask should probably refer to a different rectangle than its own parent, and one that is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want pretty easily without an OpacityMask at all since the top portion is a simple solid color You just need to add a radius to innerTopRectangle, and then draw another (non-rounded) rectangle on its bottom edge to cover the rounded corners there. I got rid of the clipping too because that wasn't necessary.

```
    Rectangle {
        id: outerRectangle
        width: (parent.width / 2) - 5 - 10;
        height: 40
        anchors.margins: 10
        border {
            width: 2
            color: "#120e0d"
        }
        radius: 5
        Rectangle {
            id: innerTopRectangle
            anchors {
                top: parent.top
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
            }
            radius: 5
            height: parent.height - levelName.height
            color: "red"

            Rectangle
            {
                // This covers the bottom rounded corners
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.radius
                color: parent.color
            }
        }  // Inner top rectable


        Text {
            id: levelName
            anchors {
                top: innerTopRectangle.bottom
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
            }
            text: name
        }  // Text
    }  // Outer rectangle
```